# How to find and increase entry process limit in the WebHost Manager (WHM) of my virtual private server (VPS)

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, vps, whm

I have a Godaddy VPS. I want to find the Entry Process limit and increase it if possible.

My VPS is going up and down probably due to high traffic. What should I do?

Comment: Have you called GoDaddy? That may be the quickest way to know.

Comment: @closetnoc well they say it's expert techsupport, need $$$s

Comment: Remind me not to call them for anything! That sounds like pure unadulterated strained bull squirt to me... they want to sell you something or pay somehow. It was worth a try! I wish I knew of an answer. Sorry. Cheers!!

Comment: I think that will need consent from the admin. Your best bet is to upgrade to a dedicated server and there you can manage process limits and the like since the server then is like your own computer that you can fully control.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your budget is, but last I looked GoDaddy VPS pricing was out of this world expensive. If you have $150 monthly budget you could easily get a fully managed dedicated server that delivers decent performance. Perhaps the best bet is to ditch GDDY and take control of your data!

- SSH `free -m` command to to see your memory performance (or check WHM » Server Status » Service Status and scroll down
- Inside WHM, you can reach out to cPanel support - see what they say. You are paying for a license so you are entitled to support
- Please [run a full benchmark](https://serverscope.io/run_benchmark) and report back with results